# Where can I find the Spring OpenId Samples for 3.1?

Tags: spring, spring-security, openid

If I understand [this](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1431?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs) correctly, there is a version of the Spring Security OpenId Sample app for version 3.1.

I'm having a tough time finding it.  I only see up to version 3.07 in the Maven repository.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-samples-openid

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The samples are no longer deployed to maven central. As the [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/sample-apps.html) mentions you can obtain them by building from source which makes sense since most of the time you will want to play around with the samples. Note that the source has moved to [github](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/source.html)